# What are some options for keeping controllers lean in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, dry

#### Background

I'm fairly new to Rails. I'm working with `Ruby 2.1.1` and `Rails 4.1` and have been reading a lot of books and tutorials but haven't quite got to the point of understanding what the best way is to keep controllers lean.

It looks like with Rails 4 there are `concerns` available for both models and controllers. At least for the controller concerns, it seems like the primary purpose is to help keep the routes and controllers [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). A good example seems to be the [defensible example at codeschool](http://rails4.codeschool.com/levels/1/challenges/6).

I also read some questions asking about similar things but couldn't find what I felt to be an exact match, especially in the context of Rails 4. What I saw seemed to say that that it would be possible to create a custom class or module and then invoke that in the controller action.

#### Specific Issues

- I have a controller where most of the actions are lean but there is one that has to do a lot of data processing and **this one has grown pretty large**.
- I created some private `helper methods` in the controller to break the processing into smaller pieces - but it seems like these *should almost be combined into a module or class?*
- The data processing really is specific to this controller and is unlikely to be used elsewhere

#### Questions

1. Am I correct in feeling like this controller should not have one large, bloated action? Or is it normal for controllers' actions to become large like this?
2. Are concerns designed to be used to help reduce this? Or are they more to help with the DRY aspects of shared actions between different controllers?
3. Would a class or a module be a good solution? Is it typical to create custom classes / methods to help keep controllers lean?
4. If the class/module approach is a good solution, how does one choose module vs class?
5. If the class/module approach is a good solution, where should these be housed and how should they be loaded / invoked? ( It seems like they should not be global "helper" functions if they are just specific to one controller )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depends -- if you have to process that data in the controller, perhaps it's the right way. But as with most things, if you show us the code, we may be able to refactor. You need to be aware of [modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity), which means you should split your code as much as possible, to encourage reuse
2. Concerns are really for providing cross-controller / cross-model modularity. For example, we use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) in several models; we've separated into different concerns, giving us the ability to change the concern once & update all the models
3. You're looking for [class methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)

---

**[Fat Model Skinny Controller](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/)**

Although not well documented, one of the core Rails patterns is to keep your controller as lean as possible. To do this, [`dhh`](http://twitter.com/dhh) recommends putting lots of your methods into your models (scopes, class methods etc) - allowing you to call them with brevity

This is a general programming pattern

---

**[Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources)**

One of my favourites - this creates the standard RESTful action interface in your controller, so you don't need to include it yourself:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

This will load `index`, `show`, `new`, `create`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy` automatically

---

[**Callbacks**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html)

Finally, you should be aware of callbacks

These allow you to run common code with a single instance method. A good example is `find`:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_post, only: [:show, :edit]

    private
    def load_post
        @post = Post.find params[:id]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option in this case is probably to use form objects. A form object exists simply to abstract away the complex interactions that are occurring in your controller. This results in cleaner more maintainable code, among other great benefits. You can read more and find some excellent examples of the technique at http://pivotallabs.com/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit/ and http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects (pro), or just search for "rails form objects".

Comment: and what if no forms are involved in the data processing? like parsing a data feed?

Comment: I apply the same basic principal, in that case. Basically, make something that you can use like `DataFeed.parse` and it will make your ObjectsInFeed and all the rest, so that you really only have a line or two in your controller. You might not want to hit a datafeed in the controller, though, unless you have throttling of some sort in place or it is otherwise restricted. You might get better mileage out of something like https://github.com/javan/whenever.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, with a datafeed I almost always make it into a gem. The extra effort is usually trivial, and it can speed up your test suites by breaking them up into relevant bits (think if you ran every gem's tests with your app tests). You also get the advantage of being able to reuse it for other projects, or publish it and become famous (unless it is some internal API, or something). I'm sure you already have, but if not, it may be worthwhile to investigate whether a similar gem already exists.